# Accessibility focus move with view when the view moved or animated

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, accessibility

Accessibility focus need to move with the previously focused view, when it is animated or moved to somewhere else.

Ex: In map view, I have already set the focus to the marker. When I give focus to next marker, the marker should come in center of the screen. It is working as expected. But the accessibility focus is still there in empty place.

Is it possible move the focus of the accessibility with that marker movement ?